# Setting a global background image or color in iOS

Tags: ios, image, background, global

Having issues with the following code.

1.) What I'm trying to achieve; - To display a global background image or color in the AppDelegate of an iOS

2.) What is happening; - The image or color displayed suggests the code is working correctly as no errors or warnings are occurring.

3.) What is the issue; - The background color or image takes up the entire screen almost like it is the up most top layer therefore I see no elements i.e. uitext, buttons etc. Just the background image..good because it's working bad because, well...users can use the app!

4.) What I have done; - Below is the code snippet in my appdelegate that I have been working with. I know it works as it is in every UIViewController and I'm trying to refactor it so I only have it in one place. Not 200!!

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{   
    //Set the background image
    if ( IDIOM == IPAD )
    {
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]];

    }
    else
    {
        //Add gradient background
        CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer yellowGradient];
        bgLayer.frame = self.window.bounds;
        [self.window.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];

    }

    //This is added so if in-app purchasing is used and the users connections fails in the middle of the transaction it will finalise the payment so it will download or give access to the purchase.
    //[ReadingsIAPHelper sharedInstance];

    return YES;
}
```

Any ideas?

Regards,
Jeremy

Comment: Have you tried sending the sub layer to the back?

Comment: Sorry...still learning objC....how would one do that?

Comment: `[self.window.layer sendSublayerToBack:bgLayer];`

Comment: Hi Wain, didn't work. It can't recognise what 'sendSublayerToBack' attribute. I found some examples to where you can set the entire string to a negative value i.e. [self.window.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:-1]; but of course that didn't work either....

Comment: Sorry just to clarify I tag above is running the second statement. the CAGradienLayer not the image.

Comment: How many sublayers does the windows layer have when you add the gradient. You can just insert the gradient layer behind any that are there.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue with UIViewController categories that is in the common included file. So each UIviewController in its init function calls [self setMyColor].

This is my code:

```
@interface ColorViewController : UIViewController
    - (void) setMyColor;
@end
```